# filtering large wiggles in signals

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to filter out large wiggles showing in a signal. Those wiggles are happening due to many signal processing layers and a final sine Fourier transform (no phase)

Here's the python code i am using to compute the sine Fourier tranform

```
def sine_f_transform(x, signal, nx):
    # x: the x axis vector in real dimension
    # signal: the y axis vector that we need fourier transfored
    # nx: the x axis vector in the reciprocal space
    nsignal = np.zeros(len(x), dtype=float)
    xsignal = x*signal
    dx      = x[1]-x[0]
    for ridx, r in enumerate(nx):
        sinxr = dx * np.sin(x*r)
        nsignal[ridx] = (2./np.pi) * np.sum( xsignal * sinxr )
    return nsignal
```

Signal vector is the result of multiple transformation. It's pointless to try to explain the meaning of it here. The main point here, i need to to filter out the large wiggles in 'transformed signal' as those are not needed and it's giving me a headache to find a general solution for that.

below you can see what the signal looks like and the sine Fourier transformed one looks like. The large wiggles that i'm desperately trying to remove are the ones in 'transformed signal'

I tried all the following:

- fft 'transformed signal' zeroing out frequencies and then ifft
- convoluting 'signal' with sinc prior to doing the sine_f_transform
- appying scipy.signal.filtfilt on Butterworth filters ...

Any help would be appreciated

thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should ask this on https://dsp.stackexchange.com/. This doesn't seem to be a programming problem.